# HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security) on Node-red

Tags: node.js, node-red, hsts

I'm trying to get Node-Red running on a network for a project. IT security at my workplace have run a security check and recommend that I enable HSTS. I'm not a network expert and have no idea how to do this.

I've enabled HTTPS in the settings.js file of node-red and to add HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security) I need to add this line to the header:

Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=60000.

Can I append this option to the Node-red settings.js file or would I have to set an environment variable outside of Node-red to do this? I've never had to do either before so can anyone offer some additional guidance on this please if this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no flag you could just set that will enable it, but you can use the `httpAdminMiddleware` option in `settings.js` to add it.

Something like the following:

```
httpAdminMiddleware: function(req,res,next) {
    res.set('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=60000');
    next();
 },
```

Just remember that once set you won't be able to disable HTTPS until 60000 seconds after the last time you access Node-RED with a given browser.